# Using property from pom to run test @FitNesseRunner.Suite

Tags: maven, fitnesse, system-properties

How can I use the settings in the POM for running tests from FitNesseRunner:

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
     <fitnesseSuiteToRun>${fitnesseSuiteToRun}</fitnesseSuiteToRun>
     <seleniumDefaultTimeout>${seleniumDefaultTimeout}</seleniumDefaultTimeout>
     <seleniumGridUrl>${seleniumGridUrl}</seleniumGridUrl>
     <seleniumBrowser>${seleniumBrowser}</seleniumBrowser>
     <seleniumDriverClass>${seleniumDriverClass}</seleniumDriverClass>
     <seleniumCapabilities>${seleniumCapabilities}</seleniumCapabilities>
     <seleniumJsonCapabilities>${seleniumJsonCapabilities}</seleniumJsonCapabilities>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

I want to use **fitnesseSuiteToRun** in myTests.myTest like this :

`@FitNesseRunner.Suite("myTests.myTest")`

Comment: Is your question how to use a property to override the `Suite` annotation-value in your code, or do you just want to run the 'myTests.myTest' suite, which is in your code?

Comment: Are you using `HsacFitNesseRunner.class` or `FitNesseRunner.class` in your `@RunWith` annotation? The pom fragment suggests the former.

Comment: I am using HsacFitNesseRunner and I want to overwrite the Suite annotation-value in my code.

Answer (score 0):

To override the `@Suite` in your code you can specify add a value for `fitnesseSuiteToRun` as system property on the maven command line. So the command to run the tests becomes something like:

`mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test -DfitnesseSuiteToRun=myTests.myTest`